# How can I encrypt the password in a SQL Server table which is linked to Access Front-End to improve security?

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, ssms, password-encryption

I'm looking to encrypt the user's password in SQL Server table. Is there a way that when a user login's in Access Front-end with their username and password, the password matches with the encrypted password in SQL Server backend and returns True that would allow User to login if the password is correct. I want to make sure that attackers are unable to view the plain text password directly.

I searched online and found out that by using SHA and Salt you can create a cryptic password but was unable to find something related to Access Front-End with SQL Server backend.

Comment: Why are you encrypting the password? Why do you need to decrypt it for authorisation? Why are you not salting and hashing?

Comment: SQL Server already stores passwords salted and hashed multiple times. The only risk is storing the password the connection string in the Access front end. You can eliminate that by using Windows authentication instead of SQL accounts, or explicitly asking the user for the account credentials before trying to connect to the database

Comment: You're confused between encryption and hashing. Encryption is when you can get back original value, while hashing is where you can't (easily). Usually for password matching, hashing is used. The idea is to store a hashed password (for example by using SHA and salt), and then when you try to login next time, you hash the entered password the same way and then compare it with the hashed password in the database. There should be a bunch of tutorials, but i would say that you generally don't want to hash in SQL Server itself, but rather do it in frontend

Comment: @CPK_2011 Access is a relational database too. Access *is* used as a front-end to SQL Server, there's even an Access to SQL Server upgrade wizard. SQL Server accounts aren't stored in tables either. Masking doesn't protect passwords.

Comment: Your purpose is not quite clear, but my article series may give you some ideas: [Utilise Microsoft's Next Generation Cryptography (CNG) API in VBA](https://github.com/GustavBrock/VBA.Cryptography).

Answer (score 0):

It is VERY often that an Access front end (FE) will use one logon, and all workstations use that one SQL logon for linking of tables.

However, if you are to adopt that EACH work station is to logon, and logon using a SQL password? Then in most cases, that will require you to re-link the tables, and those table links include the user + password in plain text.

However, you don't really have to encrypt the user + password, since you can prompt the user for user + password and simple execute a logon to SQL server in VBA. At that point, you don't even need to keep the user + password in variables, or anything at all. Once you execute the SQL logon, then all linked tables (including pass-though queries that use say SQL server stored procedures)?

They will just work.

So, there is not really much of a reason to encrypt or worry about the password WHEN you have linked tables without user + password included.

The following trick/approach also means that no user + password is exposed or used in the linked tables, and thus no real security risk.

As others noted, one other approach can be to use window authentication for the SQL logons, and thus once again, no user + password is required for the linked tables.

So, the first step is to re-link all of your tables (and pass-though queries) without ANY user + password in the connection strings.

How this works? Well, before you re-link the table(s), you simple execute a SQL logon. In fact, if you just open ONE table (that say does include the user + password), then from that point forwards, any table EVEN without a user + password will work correctly.

So, steps are:

Execute a logon to SQL server in VBA with the user + password (can be any valid user + password).

Now, without having shut down Access, run your code to re-link the tables, and do NOT include the user + password.

Now, when you start the application, you need a form for the user to enter their user + password., That form simple does the VBA logon. (And if it does not fail, then you can now close that logon form, and all linked tables will work, and work without you having to re-link, but MORE important those linked tables do NOT have nor include the UID + password in plain text.

The code to execute a logon in VBA looks like this:

```
Function TestLogin(strCon As String) As Boolean

  On Error GoTo TestError

  Dim dbs          As dao.Database
  Dim qdf          As dao.QueryDef

  Set dbs = CurrentDb()
  Set qdf = dbs.CreateQueryDef("")

   qdf.connect = strCon
   Debug.Print strCon
   
   qdf.ReturnsRecords = False

   'Any VALID SQL statement that runs on server will work below.
   ' This does assume user has enough rights to query built in
   ' System tables
   
   qdf.SQL = "SELECT 1 "
   qdf.Execute

   TestLogin = True
   
   Exit Function

   TestError:
   TestLogin = False
   Exit Function

End Function
```

So, in above, you do include the UID + password.

If above returns true, then all linked tables like "magic" will work.

And this means that say someone launches the full version of access and decides to import all of the linked tables into another Access application?
The link tables will not work!!!

In fact, even in the current application, if the user holds down shift key (to by-pass your start up form), and now from the nav pane tries to open a linked table? Nope! - the linked table will not work.

Keep in mind that ONCE you run the above code to logon to SQL server? You can't flush that uid/password cache, and ANY further attempt to test for a logon will in ALL cases ALWAYS work!!! The only way to flush that password cache is to exit MS-access.

This does mean that you can't when a user is done, say have some logoff button, and return to the logon form you make. You MUST exit MS-access to clear out that cached password. I mention this "quirk" since during testing, you might run some code to logon to MS-access (or even open a linked table with uid + password saved in that linked table). From that point onwards, ANY and ALL tests for a uid + password will ALWAYS but ALWAYS return true!!! - even for non existing UID/passwords. This information can thus save you hours upon hours of testing, since you can run some logon code, and it will always seem to work.

This also means that HUGE caution is required during the development process and linking of tables. If you during your development session at ANY time touched, or opened a linked table? Then that is cached, and there is NO possible way to flush that uid/password cache! So, then you spend the next 3 hours wondering why an invalid logon works!!! (It will !!!!).

So, to link the tables without a uid/password?

How this works is explained in detail here:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/blog/2011/04/08/power-tip-improve-the-security-of-database-connections/

However, as a short version of above?

You launch MS-access. Do NOT allow any startup code, and do NOT open ANY linked table. As noted above, the "instant" you allow ANY kind of connection to SQL server (with VBA code, or opening a form with linked table, or clicking on a linked table, then your uid/password is now cached - we do NOT want this WHEN re-linking without uid/password).

So, now access is launched, you THEN run above VBA code to logon to the database.

After running above (you DO supply a valid uid/password in the above connection string).

Now, re-link your tables, but do NOT supply a uid/logon during this re-link process.

You can easy test if you have this working. After you re-link, exit access, re-launch (again, no startup code or forms allowed).

Now, try clicking on to open a linked table. You find that it does not work. (In fact, in most cases, the ODBC logon dialog will trigger).

Now, exit access again. Launch again. Run your logon code (above) with valid uid/password.

Now click on any linked table - it should open and open without any prompts or fuss.

What the above means?

You can prompt the user on startup, logon, and at that point in NO PLACE in your connection strings, and NO PLACE in your code will have you the uid/password required, nor even hard coded in VBA. Hence, little need or reason to encrypt the uid/password.